# Utilising Service Connection in CLI tasks?

Tags: azure-devops

How does Azure Devops expose the service connection details when running CLI tasks such as BASH or Azure CLI?

Lets say I have a tool such as Packer or Terraform and I want to run tasks authenticated against azure using the service connection.

Is there some file somewhere with the clientid + secret that I can read and use? Or some system variable?

Or do I need to follow some kind of managed identity authentication flow?

I know that I can feed those details in myself via variables but I'm trying to avoid that, ideally I want a simple way just to utilise the already created service connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For YAML, I followed the answer below, and included `addSpnToEnvironment: true`.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: INIT
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
    scriptType: bash
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az --version
      az account show
      export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$servicePrincipalId
      export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$servicePrincipalKey
      export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=`az account show -o json | jq .id | tr -d '"'`
      export ARM_TENANT_ID=$tenantId
      terraform init
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 3):

Ok i can't believe I just found this. Not sure how new this option is but... if you check the Azure CLI marketplace task and look at the advanced options you will see this:

[image]

So for example to use this with Terraform you can do the following:

```
export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$servicePrincipalId
export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$servicePrincipalKey
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=`az account show -o json | jq .id`
export ARM_TENANT_ID=`az account show -o json | jq .tenantId`
```

Comment: oh thats neat, i didnt see this one xD

Comment: I had to remove the quotes from ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=`az account show -o json | jq .id | tr -d '"'`